# Unable to connect to custom signal PySide6

Tags: python-3.x, pyside6

I am trying to follow this [example](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/tutorials/basictutorial/signals_and_slots.html) to implement my own signal to connect to but to no avail. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import Signal
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QGraphicsRectItem


class MyRect(QGraphicsRectItem):

    before_select = Signal()

    def __init__(self, thing):
        super().__init__()
        self._thing = thing

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.before_select.emit()
        self._thing["selected"] = True



def on_before_select():
    print("before select")

thing = {}

rect = MyRect(thing)

rect.before_select.connect(on_before_select)
```

Basically, I am trying to just do something outside of MyRect class when something inside of it happens, in this case when it gets a mouse press event. The error I get I can't quite wrap my head around:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/stack-overflow/wtf/wtf.py", line 26, in <module>
    rect.before_select.connect(on_before_select)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'MyRect' object has no attribute ''
```

For some reason it's almost like it is behaving as though I am somehow calling `getattr(rect,"")` but I'm not. In fact, trying `getattr(rect,"before_select")` yields the same results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/stack-overflow/wtf/hmm?.py", line 26, in <module>
    getattr(rect,"before_select")
AttributeError: 'MyRect' object has no attribute ''
```

Any help would be more than welcome at this point. I swear I have gotten signals working before but I don't know what I am doing differently this time.

Comment: Signals (as much as slots and Qt properties) can only be created for QObject subclasses. QGraphicsRectItem inherits from QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem, which in turn inherits from QGraphicsItem, which is **not** a QObject. Either create a custom QObject subclass that will be used as a "signal proxy", or subclass QGraphicsObject, add the rect item as its child and expose its functions.

Comment: @musicamante yep that looks to be the issue. Still, interesting how the issue manifested itself. Thanks!

Comment: In PySide2 the error was different, a bit more verbose, but still cryptic: `RuntimeError: method 'connect' vanished!`. PyQt is more clear: `TypeError: MyRect cannot be converted to QObject in this context`. Whatever the output, the reason is the same: signals are unbound for classes, they become active only when an instance is created; at that point, the signal becomes *bound* to the instance, and then it finally exposes its `connect`, `disconnect` and `emit` functions. Since signals cannot be created for non QObjects, the signal never becomes *bound*, and those functions simply don't exist.